# Grid view overlapping on another grid view in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a grid view that declared in another grid view. My problem is the free space of upper grid view overlapping on the bottom grid view. Ho can i fix this problem ? 
This is my XAML code :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp15.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp15"
    x:Name="myWin"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="400" >
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Row="1" Column="1" MinWidth="150" MinHeight="240">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="%" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content=">\" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Content="x^2" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Content="1/x" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="CE" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="C" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Content=">" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Content="/" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="7" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Content="8" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Content="9" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Content="X" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Content="4" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Content="5" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Content="6" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Content="-" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Content="1" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Content="2" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Content="3" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" Content="+" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Content="+-" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Content="0" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2" Content="." Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="3" Content="=" Margin="2"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

In this two picture you can see my problem well 
[My whole view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHWUU.png)
[My problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfI5j.png)

Comment: Instead of row heights `80 - * - 80` try `* - Auto - *`

Comment: @funk but the height and width won't change after changing the size of window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run the code nothing is immediately cut off, so I assume you mean the buttons are cut off when resizing.

I would make the height of the inner grid "Auto" and move the MinHeight to the Window itself. I'd increase the MinHeight to something lime 350 as well if that's acceptable.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp15.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp15"
    x:Name="myWin"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="400" MinHeight="350">
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Row="1" Column="1" MinWidth="150" Height="Auto">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="%" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content=">\" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Content="x^2" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Content="1/x" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="CE" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="C" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Content=">" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Content="/" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="7" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Content="8" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Content="9" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Content="X" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Content="4" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Content="5" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Content="6" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Content="-" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Content="1" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Content="2" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Content="3" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" Content="+" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Content="+-" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Content="0" Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2" Content="." Margin="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="3" Content="=" Margin="2"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```